# Gulp: "Event.js:85" during gulp-clean

Tags: gulp

I try to delete all folders and files from my directory using gulp-clean.

My directory:

```
app
---subfolder1
---subfolder2
------subfolder
------file1
etc
```

My code:

```
gulp.task('clean',function(){
    var PATH_TO_CLEAN = '../app/**';
    if(argv.path != null)
        PATH_TO_CLEAN = '../app/'+argv.path+'/**';

    return gulp.src(PATH_TO_CLEAN, {read: false})
        .pipe(clean({force: true}))
        .on("error", handleError);
});

// Error handler
function handleError(err) {
    console.log(err.toString());
    this.emit('end');
}
```

default path is '../app' but you can delete only subfolder using parametes --path=subfolder_dir

During the execution of gulp clean this error apears:

```
[14:43:08] Starting 'clean'...
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\some_path\file.type'
    at Error (native)
```

Gulp stops but file mentioned in error is deleted.

Repeating "gulp clean" I can finally reach succes:

```
[14:53:54] Starting 'clean'...
[14:53:54] Finished 'clean' after 11 ms
```

Do you have any idea how I can avoid this error?

I tried allso [del](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/delete-files-folder.md) with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

```
gulp.task('clean',function(){
    var PATH_TO_CLEAN = '../app/**';
    if(argv.path != null)
        PATH_TO_CLEAN = '../app/'+argv.path+'/**';

    del([PATH_TO_CLEAN], {force: true});
});
```

this is not the way I would like to manage this (by pipes) but it works well.

Answer (score 0):

[gulp-clean](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean) has been deprecated and should not be used anymore.

In my project [skeletonSPA](https://github.com/elgervb/skeletonSPA), I use the following task to clean my environment:

```
gulp.task('clean', function() {
  var del = require('del');
  var vinylPaths = require('vinyl-paths');

  return gulp.src([PATH_TO_CLEAN])
  .pipe(vinylPaths(del));
});
```

This task does not break the gulp pipe.

For this to work, you'll need to install the following modules:

```
npm install del vinyl-paths
```